# How to make Nginx forward the original host name

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, load-balancing

I have an nginx server acting as a load balancer for my apache servers. I am using subdomains and my code relies on the HTTP_HOST value to perform the correct task.

When i make a request to say: `http://get.example.com` once it is forwarded the HTTP_HOST on apache becomes `example.com`.

My question is how do I make it stay the same as the original request?

Here is my nginx config:

```
upstream example.com {
  server 192.168.2.1:8909 weight=2;
  server 192.168.2.2:8909 weight=1;
  server 192.168.2.3:8909 weight=1;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://example.com;
  }
}
```

I tried adding multiple `proxy_pass`, one for each subdomain and it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass along the HTTP `Host` header. Add this to the relevant `location`:

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```